# How do I reset a Datamapper connection after Passenger forks a worker process?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger, datamapper, fork

After upgrading several parts of my Rails app (Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.4, Datamapper 1.1.0) and moving to Passenger Standalone, we started getting weird MySQL connection errors, including:

- Field-count mismatch
- Lost connection to MySQL server during query
- MySQL server has gone away

Then I remembered that Passenger forks processes and you need to re-open new connections for things like redis, memcache, etc. or the data stream will get garbled, and I found another [post](http://blog.iconara.net/2010/06/27/stability-tip-for-running-sequel-in-rails-on-passenger/) regaling similar adventures due to the same problem with MySQL.

But I also recalled reading [here](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_smart_spawning_gotcha_1_unintential_file_descriptor_sharing) that Passenger took care of the database connections automatically.

So I have two questions:

1) How do I tell DataMapper to create and use a new database connection? And/or:

2) Does forking Passenger take care of the forking database connections automatically or not?  For fork's sake... ;)

Answer (score 1):

To answer #2, no, Passenger itself does not handle closing file handles after forking. You have to manage it yourself, unless your gem does it for you.

To answer #1, I cobbled together some things I found. Add to environment.rb and let me know if it works!

```rb
if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
    PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
        if forked
            # We're in smart spawning mode.
            DataObjects::Pooling.pools.each do |pool|
              pool.dispose
            end
        else
            # We're in direct spawning mode. We don't need to do anything.
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This works for me, using it in my config/environments/production.rb file to puts some ZeroMQ specific initialisation to occur after launch of the app.